# symmetricDS node_select

Tags: database, synchronization, symmetricds

I am trying out SymmetricDS and very new at this. There are two questions I have:

Master
Client Node 1 (location_id = 001)
Client Node 2 (location_id = 002)

The table structure I have:
tbl_customer (customer_id, first_name, last_name)
tbl_customer_details (customer_id, location_id, details)

1) When syncing Master to Client Nodes, how do I sync tbl_customer where data is in a certain location_id? As you can see from our structure, in SQL we have to join tbl_customer to tbl_customer_details on customer_id where location_id = X
How can I tell SymmetricDS to sync accordingly and how do I designate each client node with a location ID?

2) Is it possible to sync from a view on client node to a table on master or can it only be from table to table?

Answer (score 1):

1) Use `sym_router` table's column `router_type` with value `subselect` and then in the column `router_expression` write an SQL snippet `c.external_id in (SELECT_STATEMENT_RETURNING_LOCATION_IDS)` for both `tbl_customer` and `tbl_customer_details`.

2) If the database implementation allows defining triggers for the views **and** SymmetricDS supports it then yes, it's possible.

Comment: Great - does c.external_id represent the ID I setup for each node?

Comment: Yes it does represent the external id set up in the symmetric-ds.properties file.